# presto from_unixtime function is right?

Tags: nosql, presto

i make a query about bigint to timestamp and value is '1494257400'

i will use a presto query
but presto is not collect result about from_unixtime() function.

hive version.

`select from_unixtime(1494257400)  result : '2017-05-09 00:30:00'`

presto version.

Blockquote

`select from_unixtime(1494257400) result : '2017-05-08 08:30:00'`

hive gave a collect result, but presto is not collect result. how i can solve about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presto `from_unixtime` returns you a date at UTC when the one from Hive returns you a date on your local time zone.

According to https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF, `from_unixtime`:

> Converts the number of seconds from unix epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00
>   UTC) to a string representing the timestamp of that moment in the
>   current system time zone in the format of "1970-01-01 00:00:00".

The output of Hive is not that good because ISO formatted strings should show GMT data if they have any which are not GMT+00.

With Hive, you can use  `to_utc_timestamp({any primitive type} ts, string timezone)` to convert your timestamp to the proper timezones. Take a look at the manual whose link is provided above.

Comment: thx... i understand it .
but i don't know how i can change a query to receive a same result ..;_;..
would you give me a sample presto query?

Comment: to_utc_timestamp , that is not presto function..right?

Comment: There is also an overload of Presto's `from_unixtime` that takes a timezone string. So, I would change the query to `select from_unixtime(1494257400, 'America/New_York')` to get my local result. I've also noticed that DataGrip always converts to local timezone, so watch out for your tools doing similar conversions.